# Symfony: How to save data from sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice with multiple checkboxes

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have problem with save data from choices widget.
Here is part of schema:

```
Client:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    grupy:
      type: array
  options:
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
    charset: utf8   
  relations:
    Grupy:
      type: many
      local: grupy
      foreign: id
      class: KlientGrupy

KlientGrupy:
  options:
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
    charset: utf8
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    item:
      type: string(255)
  relations:
    Klienci:
      type: many
      local: id
      foreign: grupy
```

ClientForm class:

```
class ClientForm extends BaseClientForm
{

    public function configure()
    {
        $this->widgetSchema['grupy']->setOption('multiple', true);
        $this->widgetSchema['grupy']->setOption('expanded', true);
        $this->widgetSchema['grupy']->setOption('add_empty', false);
        $this->widgetSchema['grupy']->setAttribute('class', 'checkBoxLabel');

    }

}
```

BaseClientForm class:

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
  'id'              => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
  'grupy'           => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('Grupy'), 'add_empty' => true)),
));
```

When i save with one checkbox then all is ok, but when i try do it for more than one i get that problem:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Comment: Ok I found sollution here:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#relationships:join-table-associations:many-to-many

If u have problem write here I will try to help You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find answer in comment in my question